# PHP redirecting from submitted form

Tags: php, forms, redirect

My php file works fine but I cant figure out how to make it redirect to another page once it has been submitted?

Code is below, thank you!

```
<?php

$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "secret";

$message = $_POST["message"];


if($_POST){
    mail ($to, $subject, $message);
    header("Location: sent.html"); 
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Try `if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){...}` instead. Plus, you may be outputting before header. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you may get an error `Headers already sent...`; which will explain it.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with if($_POST) ?

Comment: If there is text (message), submit form to the email address, php is a new venture for me so I may have this misunderstood but it seems to deliever the message?

Comment: I don't know, does it deliver the message, and are you not using error reporting as I stated earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue you will have with your code is that you do "sunny-day" coding, where the world is nice and dandy and everything will work just fine. However, one small problem and your code will break! You need to always program for worst case scenarios as much as you can!

```
<?php
//first set up code to show errors - REMOVE these two lines in production env!
ini_set("display_errors", 1); //ask php to display errors
error_reporting(E_ALL); //display ALL errors (notices, warnings, fatals et al)...

$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "secret";
$success = "sent.html";

//Ok, maybe you dont need to be THIS paranoid ... :) 
//however this is for illustration purposes...
if(array_key_exists("message", $_POST)) //is there message field in POST? 
{
    $message = $_POST['message']; //get it!
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message)) //try to sent out the email..
    {
        //if we are here, it means email was sent, now lets redirect...
        if(headers_sent()) //have we already sent out any headers?
        {
        //yes we have, so header() will not work, lets use javascript to redirect
        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='".$success."';</script>";
        }
        else
        {
        //headers have not been sent yet, we can use header()...
        header("Location: sent.html");
        }
    }
    else //our mail did not go, lets die() with an error
    {
        die("Unable to send email. Please check mail settings.");
        //instead of the above die() you could redirect to a proper error page.
        //I am leaving that out for brevity's sake
    }
}
else
{
    die("Where art thou, O' elusive message?");
    //instead of the above die() you could redirect to a proper error page.
    //I am leaving that out for brevity's sake. 
}
?>
```

As you can see, one of the fundamental ideas behind programming is to think about most of the things that can go wrong, when writing a code, and write accommodating conditions, so that they get handled gracefully...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `isset()` or `empty()`:

```
<?php

$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "secret";

if (isset($_POST['message'])){
    // Message is given
    //Alternatively, you can see if it's set and not empty:
    // if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {}
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    mail ($to, $subject, $message);
    header("Location: sent.html");
    exit();
}
```